# Error: Database connection failed

Tags: moodle

Кто знаком с `moodle`, подскажите. Вчера установил локально на своем ПК, создал базу, все было ок, а сегодня ошибка:

> Error: Database connection failed.
> It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.
> The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php

Как все вернуть к работе?

Answer (score 0):

На оф. форуме Moodle люди сталкивались с такой ошибкой при использовании Oracle XE, причем при правильных настройках config.php и корректно запущенной соответствующей службе Oracle.